# How to auto-load data in the test database before to test my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and RSpec 2. I would like to auto-load seed data in the *test* database before I tesst my application. That is, *at the testing start up time (when I run tests) I would like to "auto-populate"\"auto-boot" the test database*.

**How can I populate the database with seed data?**

---

*P.S.*: As I read around, (maybe) I should populate the test database by adding some code to the `/spec/spec_helper.rb` file... but *what code and how?*

In my `task/custom.rake` file I have:

```
namespace :test do
  desc "Boot database"
  task :boot => [:load, :seed] do
  end

  desc "Reboot database"
  task :reboot => [:purge, :boot] do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to just invoke the seed rake task, I'd do something like this:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
```

But, I'd recommend using Fixtures (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures).

Or even better a fixture replacement like Factory Girl (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), whereby you can load dummy data with all the associated data.  This is a much less brittle approach.

Comment: I am already using Fixtures and Factory Girl. I would like to populate just the test database (like I make for with development database).

Comment: +1 for factory_girl.  You can also combine it with [forgery](https://github.com/sevenwire/forgery) or [similar](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/random_data_generation.html) for even more fun.