# Rails How to use FactoryGirl in Seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, factory-bot

I want to have the Seeds.rb file run a method in a file from the `Rails.root.join('spec')` directory which will fill the database with data generated by FactoryGirl. Lets call this file "helpers.rb" with the method "seed_data"

> Edit: `require Rails.root.join('spec','helpers.rb')` links the file.
>   [source](http://www.funonrails.com/2010/03/require-file-in-rails-environment.html)

This method I want to use in a `before(:all) do seed_data end` to seed the test database and `rake db:seed` for development/production databases with the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Seeds.rb

```
require Rails.root.join('spec','helpers.rb')
require 'rubygems'           #so it can load gems
require 'factory_girl_rails' #so it can run in development
seed_data
```

## spec/helpers.rb

```
def seed_data
  Factory.create(:user)
end
```